# Comparar faixa de valores

Tags: php, algoritmo

O código abaixo compara um valor e de acordo com esse valor gera uma porcentagem e funciona. Porém gostaria de uma forma mais prática, seja função ou outra estrutura, pois essas faixas de valores podem ser muito grandes.

Como simplificar a estrutura abaixo?

```
    if($valor>0 and $valor<=5000){
        $percentual = 0.41;
    }elseif($valor>5000 and $valor<=10000){
        $percentual = 0.42;
    }elseif($valor>10000 and $valor<=15000){
        $percentual = 0.43;
    }elseif($valor>15000 and $valor<=20000){
        $percentual = 0.44;
    }elseif($valor>20000 and $valor<=25000){
        $percentual = 0.5;
    }elseif($valor>25000 and $valor<=30000){
        $percentual = 0.57;
    }elseif($valor>30000 and $valor<=35000){
        $percentual = 0.6;
    }elseif($valor>35000 and $valor<=40000){
        $percentual = 0.8;
    }elseif($valor>40000 and $valor<=45000){
        $percentual = 0.84;
    }elseif($valor>45000 and $valor<=50000){
        $percentual = 0.87;
    }elseif($valor>50000 and $valor<=55000){
        $percentual = 0.92;
    }elseif($valor>55000 and $valor<=60000){
        $percentual = 1.0;
    }elseif($valor>60000 and $valor<=65000){
        $percentual = 1.02;
    }elseif($valor>65000 and $valor<=70000){
        $percentual = 1.23;
    }elseif($valor>70000 and $valor<=75000){
        $percentual = 1.25;
    }elseif($valor>75000 and $valor<=80000){
        $percentual = 2;
    }else{
        $percentual = 5;
    }
```

O "passo" entre uma faixa e outra sempre será fixa. No caso do exemplo acima de 5000. Mas o limite pode variar, no exemplo acima foi de 0 até 80000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta do Maniero é bem prática, mas para manutenção fica confuso pois caso você queira alterar a porcentagem de uma faixa fica confuso de saber qual o item da array a alterar.

Por exemplo, se você quiser alterar a porcentagem da faixa `$valor>50000 e $valor<=55000` você não vai saber qual item (índice) da array para alterar, ainda mais se forem muitos. Você terá que saber qual o índice da faixa e contar com os dedos até chegar no índice certo, correndo ainda risco de alterar o índice errado.

Por exemplo, se você tiver valores de 0 até 200 mil (você disse que isso pode variar), você terá uma array com 40 itens (os valores abaixo são ilustrativos):

```
$percentuais = Array(
0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1,
1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2,
2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3,
3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4,
);
```

Digamos que você queira alterar a faixa de `>70000 e <=75000`, qual item da array acima você irá alterar? Fica difícil saber.

A ideia da resposta do Kayo é interessante em termos de manutenção, porém eu faria de forma mais simples, usando arrays com apenas dois itens:

```
$faixas = [
   [5000, .41],
   [10000, .42],
   [15000, .43],
   [20000, .44],
   [25000, .5],
   [30000, .57]
];
```

Nas arrays coloquei no primeiro item o valor máximo e no segundo item o percentual.

Fazendo um `foreach` você consegue saber qual dessas arrays possui um valor onde a variável `$valor` se encaixa com os mesmos critérios do seu código original:

```
foreach($faixas as $v){
   if($valor <= $v[0]){
      $porcentagem = $v[1];
      break;
   }
}
```

Se `$valor`, por exemplo, for `2000`, a primeira array (onde o índice `[0]` é `5000`) já satisfaz e o laço é cancelado com `break`, atribuindo à variável `$porcentagem` o valor do índice `[1]` dessa array. Se `$valor` for `6000`, irá passar direto da primeira array e parar na segunda, e assim por diante.

Acho essa forma mais fácil de manter. Por exemplo, caso você queira penas alterar a porcentagem da faixa que vai de `15001` a `20000`, você irá alterar apenas a array:

```
[20000, .44]
```

No caso de `$valor` ser menor ou igual a `0` ou maior que o valor da última faixa, você faz um `if` atribuindo o valor `5` à variável `$porcentagem`, caso contrário entra no `else` e faz o `foreach`. Código completo:

```
$valor = 5000;

$faixas = [
   [5000, .41],
   [10000, .42],
   [15000, .43],
   [20000, .44],
   [25000, .5],
   [30000, .57]
];

if($valor > end($faixas)[0] || $valor < 1){
   $porcentagem = 5;
}else{
   foreach($faixas as $v){
      if($valor <= $v[0]){
         $porcentagem = $v[1];
         break;
      }
   }
}

echo $porcentagem; // 0.41
```

Veja funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/3yHXMP).

**Só uma observação:** seu código não mostra, mas caso você esteja verificando antes se `$valor` é maior que `0` (o que acho provável), não precisa colocar a condição `|| $valor < 1` no `if`. Basta deixar assim:

```
if($valor > end($faixas)[0]){
```

Comment: Realmente para manutenção é mais claro. Obrigado

Comment: Ótima resposta, concordo que pra manutenção será bem mais simples de entender, principalmente se a pessoa que for dar manutenção não for a mesma que fez o código.

Comment: Dessa forma as faixas poderiam ser "irregulares" ? `$valor>0 and $valor<=2365`e `$valor>2365 and $valor<=3122` ?

Comment: @PedroAugusto Com certeza. Desde que cada array fique na ordem crescente como coloquei na resposta, não há problema algum.

Answer (score 6):

Como as faixas são regulares fica bem fácil porque pode usar só a matemática e um *array* com os valores.

Eu não coloquei todos os valores (sem eles falharia nas faixas que eu não coloquei), mas dá para entender assim. tem só uma exceção quando chega no valor limite. Não tratei valores fora da faixa, como negativos, porque o original não trata.

```
$valor = 10000;
$percentuais = Array(0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.5, 0.6);
$percentual = $valor > 80000 ? 5 : $percentuais[($valor - 1) / 5000];
echo $percentual;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tLLUZ0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/RangeForPercentphp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/RangeForPercent.php).

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar um `array` com todos os valores possíveis e percorrer o mesmo e fazer apenas um `if` dentro do `foreach`, acredito que fique melhor para dar manutenção e também para entender o código.

```
$data = [
    [
        'start' => 0,
        'end' => 5000,
        'percentage' => 0.41,
    ],
    [
        'start' => 5000,
        'end' => 10000,
        'percentage' => 0.42,
    ],
    [
        'start' => 10000,
        'end' => 15000,
        'percentage' => 0.43,
    ]
];


$valor = 11000;
$percentage = 0;

if ($valor > end($data)['end']) {
    $percentage = 5;    
} else {
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        if ($valor > $value['start'] && $valor <= $value['end']) {
            $percentage = $value['percentage'];     
            break;
        }
    }   
}

echo $percentage;

// Valor impresso: 0.43
```

Comment: Como você define a necessidade de ter um "teto" de faixa, e não tem tratamento para "teto aberto", seu código não funcionará para o caso `80001`.

Comment: Sim você tem razão mas ai é só colocar um `else` e definir `$percentage` igual a 5.